# Unable to use Stack Exchange app when stackexchange.com is blocked, but not sites that aren't hosted there

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app, blocked

I am sometimes in an environment where `stackexchange.com` and all of its subdomains are blocked, but sites that are hosted on other domains are allowed, i. e. we are only allowed access to Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Stack Apps. When I try to use the Stack Exchange Android App, it constantly gives me connection errors, possibly because it tries to connect to `stackexchange.com`. Shouldn't the app also allow access to these five sites, but not to others?

Comment: Is that a local rule that stackexchange.com is blocked? Wouldn't it be easier to get the blocking lifted?